# Efficient way to match a string from lists and return a string

Tags: python

Refer to the following code:

```
def checkPortInList(resource, port):
  # check all ports
  for row in resource:
    rPort = row[0]
    if rPort == port:
      return True
  return False

def checkPorts()
    campus = input('Are you in the campus?')
    port = input('What port are you using?')
    if campus == 'No':
        resource1 = [["Gi0/0","Harold"],["Gi0/2","George"]]
        resource4 = [["Gi0/1","Rodrick"],["Gi3/2","Rowley"]]
        if checkPortInList(resource1, port)
            return 'ERROR10'
        if checkPortInList(resource4, port)
            return 'ERROR14'
    elif campus == 'Yes':
        resource1 = [["Gi0/0","Harold"],["Gi0/2","George"]]
        resource2 = [["Gi1/0","Rick"],["Gi1/2","Morty"]]
        resource3 = [["Gi2/0","Tom"],["Gi2/2","Jerry"]]
        resource4 = [["Gi0/1","Rodrick"],["Gi3/2","Rowley"]]
        if checkPortInList(resource1, port)
            return 'ERROR21'
        if checkPortInList(resource2, port)
            return 'ERROR22'
        if checkPortInList(resource3, port)
            return 'ERROR23'
        if checkPortInList(resource4, port)
            return 'ERROR25'
```

I want to provide better error codes, stop using `checkPortInList` and start using the following function:

```
def checkPortInListWDesc(resource, port):
    for row in resource:
        rPort = row[0]
        if rPort == port:
            rDesc = row[1]
            return rDesc
    return ''
```

but then `checkPorts()` will be cumbersome:

```
def checkPortsWDesc():
    campus = input('Are you in the campus?')
    port = input('What port are you using?')
    if campus == 'No':
        resource1 = [["Gi0/0","Harold"],["Gi0/2","George"]]
        resource4 = [["Gi0/1","Rodrick"],["Gi3/2","Rowley"]]
        r1 = checkPortInListWDesc(resource1, port)
        if r1:
            return 'ERROR10: Cpt. Underwear port is taken by ' + r1
        r4 = checkPortInListWDesc(resource4, port)
        if r4:
            return 'ERROR14: Whimpy Kid port is taken by ' + r4
    elif campus == 'Yes':
        resource1 = [["Gi0/0","Harold"],["Gi0/2","George"]]
        resource2 = [["Gi1/0","Rick"],["Gi1/2","Morty"]]
        resource3 = [["Gi2/0","Tom"],["Gi2/2","Jerry"]]
        resource4 = [["Gi0/1","Rodrick"],["Gi3/2","Rowley"]]
        r1 = checkPortInListWDesc(resource1, port)
        if r1:
            return 'ERROR21: Cpt. Underwear port is taken by ' + r1
        r2 = checkPortInListWDesc(resource2, port)
        if r2:
            return 'ERROR22: Rick&Morty port is taken by ' + r2
        r3 = checkPortInListWDesc(resource3, port)
        if r3:
            return 'ERROR23: Tom&Jerry port is taken by ' + r3
        r4 = checkPortInListWDesc(resource4, port)
        if r4:
            return 'ERROR25: Whimpy Kid port is taken by ' + r4
```

In real life, I have many if-else and many lists. Each `if` tests different lists and amount of lists. Is there an efficient way to do this?

```
r2 = checkPortInListWDesc(resource2, port)
if r2:
    return 'ERROR: port is taken by ' + r2
```

maybe ternary operation? tried, but it doesnt work:

```
print('ERROR: Cpt. Underwear port is taken by ' + r1 if (r1 = checkPortInListWDesc(resource1, port)))
if (r1 = checkPortInListWDesc(resource1, port)) : print('ERROR: Cpt. Underwear port is taken by ' + r1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to how you have pairings of ports and names in your resource lists, you can pair the resources with the port name.

```py
resources = [
    ('Cpt. Underwear', [["Gi0/0","Harold"],["Gi0/2","George"]]),
    ('Rick&Morty', [["Gi1/0","Rick"],["Gi1/2","Morty"]]),
    ('Tom&Jerry', [["Gi2/0","Tom"],["Gi2/2","Jerry"]])
    ('Whimpy Kid', [["Gi0/1","Rodrick"],["Gi3/2","Rowley"]]),
]
```

From there we are able to loop over each item to perform the check.

```py
def checkPortsWDesc():
    campus = input('Are you in the campus?')
    port = input('What port are you using?')
    resources = [
        ('Cpt. Underwear', [["Gi0/0","Harold"],["Gi0/2","George"]]),
        ('Rick&Morty', [["Gi1/0","Rick"],["Gi1/2","Morty"]]),
        ('Tom&Jerry', [["Gi2/0","Tom"],["Gi2/2","Jerry"]])
        ('Whimpy Kid', [["Gi0/1","Rodrick"],["Gi3/2","Rowley"]]),
    ]
    if campus == 'No':
        for resource_index in [0, 3]:
            port_name, port_list = resources[resource_index]
            r = checkPortInListWDesc(port_list, port)
            if r:
                return f'ERROR: {port_name} port is taken by {r}'

    elif campus == 'Yes':
        for (port_name, port_list) in resources:
            r = checkPortInListWDesc(port_list, port)
            if r:
                return f'ERROR: {port_name} port is taken by {r}'
```

You can further change the data structure for resources to use a dictionary instead to make searching simpler.

```py
def checkPortsWDesc():
    campus = input('Are you in the campus?')
    port = input('What port are you using?')
    resources = [
        ('Cpt. Underwear', { "Gi0/0": "Harold" , "Gi0/2": "George" }),
        ('Rick&Morty', { "Gi1/0": "Rick", "Gi1/2": "Morty" }),
        ('Tom&Jerry', { "Gi2/0": "Tom", "Gi2/2": "Jerry" }),
        ('Whimpy Kid', { "Gi0/1": "Rodrick", "Gi3/2": "Rowley" })
    ]
    if campus == 'No':
        for resource_index in [0, 3]:
            port_name, ports in resources[resource_index]
            r = ports.get(port)
            if r:
                return f'ERROR: {port_name} port is taken by {r}'

    elif campus == 'Yes':
        for port_name, ports in resources:
            r = ports.get(port)
            if r:
                return f'ERROR: {port_name} port is taken by {r}'
```

**Edit**: Extending the resources list items to contain more error info

```py
def checkPortsWDesc():
    campus = input('Are you in the campus?')
    port = input('What port are you using?')
    resources = [
        ('Cpt. Underwear', { "Gi0/0": "Harold" , "Gi0/2": "George" }, (10, 21)),
        ('Rick&Morty', { "Gi1/0": "Rick", "Gi1/2": "Morty" }, (0, 22)),
        ('Tom&Jerry', { "Gi2/0": "Tom", "Gi2/2": "Jerry" }, (0, 23)),
        ('Whimpy Kid', { "Gi0/1": "Rodrick", "Gi3/2": "Rowley" }, (14, 25))
    ]
    if campus == 'No':
        for resource_index in [0, 3]:
            port_name, ports, error_codes in resources[resource_index]
            r = ports.get(port)
            if r:
                return f'ERROR{error_codes[0]}: {port_name} port is taken by {r}'

    elif campus == 'Yes':
        for port_name, ports, error_codes in resources:
            r = ports.get(port)
            if r:
                return f'ERROR{error_codes[1]}: {port_name} port is taken by {r}'
```

Comment: Thanks!
i wanted to say that the error messages are custom and different for every if-else. so building a different data structure wont solve it. i was thinking about something like ternary operation

Comment: Can you update your question with the requirements and example then? How custom are they?

Comment: I have updated it. Thanks!!
i cant use the data structure to add an error message (or part of the error message, since every if-else should provide a different error message. just for the sake of the example i added numbers to the error messages.

Comment: @arnon are there any rules to the additional information in the error codes? Otherwise you can extend the resources data structure (or create a new one) to contain the error information and build the error string

Comment: unfortunatly no.

Comment: I've added another example where error info is added to the resource items to contain the error codes. Is there more that can change?

Comment: oh! 
it will be too much to manage. for every new branch or use case i'll have to rebuild the data. if i can only get an error and match in a single line :(

Comment: If you want to keep all the if statements then the shortest you can get is this one-liner `if (r := checkPortInListWDesc(resource1, port)): return f'ERROR21: Cpt. Underwear port is taken by {r}'`

Comment: thanks!! 
although less readable, but definatly will make the code much (MUCH) shorter